# how can I observe a change in a python var

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, observers, pyperclip

Hi I'm trying to catch the change in the paperclip of my computer with the library pyperclip something same as

```
url=pyperclip.paste()
```

I want to create a thread which can append all the urls into a list my script, but I don't know how to could I do it

Thanks for your time and help c:

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the documentation or the source code at all?  That's all I did.  `pyperclip` supports `waitForPaste` and `waitForNewPaste` methods that can do this.